# How to filter rows based off of a subset of column conditions in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, filtering

I have some timepoint data of the following format:

| Genotype | Condition | Animal ID | D1 | D2 | PI3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ctrl | vehicle | 1M123 | 0 | -18 | -30 |
| ko | treatment | 2M123 | 0 | -7 | -15 |
| ctrl | vehicle | 3M123 | 0 | -18 | -30 |
| ko | treatment | 4M123 | 0 | -7 | -15 |

I would like to create a function which filters the values of the timepoint columns (D1,D2,PI3) for values above -20.5, and to keep NA's. The timepoint names vary per file however they always start with D or PI.

I believe something like the code below works, however I would like to know if there is a better way.

```
library(dplyr)

filter.data<-function(mydata){
  filtered<-mydata %>%
    filter(
      across(
        .cols=starts_with(c("D","PI")),
        .fns=any_vars(.>(-20.5)|is.na(.))
      )
    )
  return(filtered)
}
```

Additionally, I would also like to create a function which returns a table of the removed data (i.e the opposite filter) to keep track of removed data points. In the .fns line of the code when I reverse the condition (i.e .< (-20.5) & !is.na(.)), it does not filter correctly.

Filtering for values above -20.5 works:

```
filter.data<-function(mydata){
  filtered<-mydata %>%
    filter(
      across(
        .cols=starts_with(c("D","PI")),
        .fns=any_vars(.>(-20.5)|is.na(.))
      )
    )
  return(filtered)
}
```

Filtering for values below -20.5 does not work:

```
rm.data<-function(mydata){
  filtered<-mydata %>%
    filter(
      across(
        .cols=starts_with(c("D","PI")),
        .fns=any_vars(.<(-20.5)& !is.na(.))
      )
    )
  return(rm.data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```r
fun <- function(dat) {
  filter(dat, if_any(starts_with(c("D", "PI")), ~ is.na(.) | . > -20.5))
}
fun(quux)
#   Genotype Condition Animal.ID D1  D2 PI3
# 1     ctrl   vehicle     1M123  0 -18 -30
# 2       ko treatment     2M123  0  -7 -15
# 3     ctrl   vehicle     3M123  0 -18 -30
# 4       ko treatment     4M123  0  -7 -15
```